# Can I split an input that doesnt have spaces?

Tags: python, string, input, split

I'm attempting to create a program that relates to poker using python.
When someone inputs `"9H"`, is there a way to separate the `9` from the `H`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to break a string into individual characters is to call [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) on it:

```
>>> list("9H")
['9', 'H']
>>>
```

This will iterate over the string and collect its characters into a new list object.

Answer (score 3):

You can access each individual character in a string using its index, there's no need to convert the input to a list. If it's just two characters, you can always do this:

```
card = '9H'
number, suit = card[0], card[1]
```

Or even simpler, we can unpack the elements in the string:

```
number, suit = card
```

Now `number` will contain the string value `'9'` and `suit` will be equal to `'H'`. Be careful with the edge case though - how do we process a card such as `'10S'`? a bit clunkier, but we can use regular expressions, and this will work for all valid inputs of cards:

```
import re
card = '10S'
number, suit = re.findall(r'(\d+)(\D)', card)[0]
```

Comment: `number, suit = card` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to a list:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 30 2014, 18:30:15)
>>> "example"[0]
'e'
>>> "example"[1]
'x'
>>> list("example")
['e', 'x', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that all these answers are scary if you'll be expecting input like `10H` rather than `TH`. In which case I'd consider stripping the last token (which should always be a single character representing the suit) from the rest and doing that instead.

```
your_input = "10H"
rank, suit = your_input[:-1], your_input[-1]
```

This plays nicely for more "normal" inputs as well:

```
rank, suit = "9H"[:-1], "9H"[-1]
```